# Flink TaskManagers do not start until job is submitted in YARN cluster

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink, amazon-emr

I am using Amazon EMR to run Flink Cluster on YARN. My setup consists of m4.large instances for 1 master and 2 core nodes. I have started the Flink CLuster on YARN with the command: `flink-yarn-session -n 2 -d -tm 4096 -s 4`.

Flink Job Manager and Application Manager starts but there are no Task Managers running. The Flink Web interface shows 0 for task managers, task slots and slots available. However when I submit a job to flink cluster, then Task Managers get allocated and the job runs and the Web UI shows correct values as expected and goes back to 0 once the job is complete.

I would like Task Managers to be running even when no Job is submitted as I want to use Flink's REST API to monitor and modify parallelism based on the available slots value.

Is there a configuration that I've missed which prevents Task Managers from running all the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flink's behavior was changed in FLIP-6 to allow dynamic resource allocation. From Flink version 1.5.0, one can put `mode: legacy` in flink-conf.yaml to run Flink in the old mode where Task Managers will be started along with Job Manager.

Comment: [FLIP-6](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=65147077). I wasn't able to find a `mode:legacy` option in FLIP-6 or the Flink docs. Any idea if this is still possible?

Comment: The legacy mode configuration is mentioned in the Flink 1.5.0 release notes: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/release-notes/flink-1.5.html
Here, it is indicated that it would be removed in the next version. Although a quick search reveals that this configuration is available till 1.8.0 and is removed from 1.9.0 version.