# How to view Flink web UI when using AWS EMR

Tags: apache-flink

I have deployed the EMR cluster and have been able to view the hadoop web ui, but I don't see the session to select to view the Flink web UI. I was planning on submitting jobs through it so nothing is running on the cluster currently. I did select the flink 1.6.2 resource to install on the cluster via the aws console when setting it up. What am I missing?

Comment: Amazon explains how to set this up in their documentation. See the page on [Finding the Flink Web Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/flink-web-interface.html).

Comment: Right, but there is nothing in that row. There are no applications running yet. I am looking to submit the job through the web UI.

Comment: Right. I think this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439318/flink-taskmanagers-do-not-start-until-job-is-submitted-in-yarn-cluster.

Comment: That is a big help! I haven't had a chance to test yet. Been wrapped up in other things. But will test today.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!